# Xpath can't find element and return none

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

im facing a problem with this page :

https://www.ouedkniss.com/op%C3%A9rateur-sur-machine-bejaia-boudjellil-algerie-offres-d-emploi-d19820393

i want to **scrape** this elements:

Employeur : SARL UFMATP AZIEZ ET ASSOCIES

Poste : Opérateur sur machine

But when i use xpath to find element it cant see them and jump to other element

```
        'Titre': response.xpath("normalize-space(//h1[@id='Title']/text())").get(),
        
        'Boss':response.xpath("//*[@id="Employeur"]/span/text()").get(),
```

this script return a value for 'Titre'  but none for Boss, i cheked if there are an iframe but not
any help would be appreciated

```
import scrapy
import requests
from scrapy.http import Request
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from scrapy import Selector
from sidahmed.items import sidahmedItem
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
custom_settings = {
    'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'sidahmed.pipelines.MyImagesPipeline': 1},
}

starting_number = 1
number_of_pages = 10
class sidahmed (scrapy.Spider):
   name = "sidahmed"
   allowed_domains = ["ouedkniss.com"]
   start_urls =  ["https://www.ouedkniss.com/emploi_demandes/industrie-production/{}".format(i) for i in range(1)]
   def __init__(self):
        self.page_number = 1



  # def parse(self, response):
        #print (self.page_number)
        #print ("----------")
        #sel = Selector(response)
        #titles = sel.xpath("//div[@class='magicCard']")
        #if not titles:
            #raise CloseSpider('No more pages')

   #def start_requests(self):
        #for i in range (self.page_number, number_of_pages, +1):
            #suivante ="[adressesite % i]"
            #yield Request(suivante, callback=self.parse)
   def parse (self, response):
       urls=response.xpath("//a[@class = 'button button_details']/@href"). extract ()

       for p in urls:
           url = urljoin(response.url, p)
           yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_annonces)


   def parse_annonces(self, response):
       for annonce in response.xpath("//div[@id='annonce']"):

           yield {
                   'Titre': response.xpath("normalize-space(//h1[@id='Title']/text())").get(),
            #'Boss': response.xpath("//*[@id='Sexe']/span[contains(., 'Homme')]").get(),
             'Boss': response.xpath("//*[@id='Employeur']/span/text()").get()
                      #'Ville': response.xpath("normalize-space(//h2[@class='country-wilaya']/text())").get(),
            #'Annonceur': response.xpath("normalize-space(//p[@class='nom-entreprise orange']/text())").get(),
            #'Prix': response.xpath("normalize-space(//span[@itemprop='price']/text())").get(),
            #'Boitevitesse':response.xpath("normalize-space(//li[2][@class='col-md-6']/text())").get(),
            #'Carburant':response.xpath("normalize-space(//li[3][@class='col-md-6']/text())").get(),
            #'Annee':response.xpath("normalize-space(//li[4][@class='col-md-6']/text())").get(),
            #'Etat':response.xpath("normalize-space(//li[5][@class='col-md-6']/text())").get(),
            #'Statut': response.xpath("normalize-space(//p[@class='type-inscription orange']/text())").get(),
            #'Description': response.xpath("normalize-space(//div[@id='Description']/node()/text())").get(),
            #'Tel': response.xpath("normalize-space(//div[@class='contact-box']//p[last()]/text())").get(),
            #'index':response.xpath("//span[@id='imgrightspan']/text()").get(),
            #'image_urls': response.xpath("//ul[@id='foo3']//li//img/@src").extract()

                 }
            

       #self.page_number += 1
       #yield Request(adressesite % self.page_number)
```

items.py

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
# Define here the models for your scraped items
#
# See documentation in:
# https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

    import scrapy
    from scrapy.item import Item
    
    class sidahmedItem(scrapy.Item):
        # define the fields for your item here like:
        # name = scrapy.Field()
        image_urls=scrapy.Field()
        images=scrapy.Field()
        Titre = scrapy.Field()
        Ville = scrapy.Field()
        Carburant = scrapy.Field()
        Boss = scrapy.Field()
        Prix = scrapy.Field()
        Statut = scrapy.Field()
        Description = scrapy.Field()
        Tel = scrapy.Field()
        index =scrapy.Field()
```

settings.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Scrapy settings for sidahmed project
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only settings considspidered important or
# commonly used. You can find more settings consulting the documentation:
#
#     https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
#     https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#     https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html

BOT_NAME = 'sidahmed'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['sidahmed.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'sidahmed.spiders'
#ITEM_PIPELINES = {'sidahmed.pipelines.MyFilesPipeline': 1}
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'sidahmed.pipelines.MyImagesPipeline': 1}
#ITEM_PIPELINES = {'sidahmed.pipelines.CustomImagesPipeline': 1,}
IMAGES_STORE = "./images"




# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```

Comment: Seems to work for me - maybe change your double quote within the response.xpath's to single quotes: `response.xpath("//*[@id='Employeur']/span/text()").get()`

Comment: Tried to use single cote but i have always None  
for exemple i have this : 
{'Titre': 'Master 2 en mécanique', 'Boss': None}

Comment: Thank you guys i found the problem , it was a wrong start url ,
it should be this : "https://www.ouedkniss.com/emploi_offres/industrie-production
but i put this :
https://www.ouedkniss.com/emploi_demandes/industrie-production
so its normal it cant find the element it is not on the page 
thank you